# C++ template determine function return type

Tags: c++, templates

How can I go about determining return type of a member generic function?

```
    template<class E>
    struct result<E> {
        // E has member function data(), I need to know its return type
        typedef typename &E::data type;
    };
```

is it possible to do it in generic way?
I know there is `boost:: result_of` but for my purposes it lacks specializations (if I understood correctly, return type must be specialized).
boost implementation would be great.

Comment: Probably, you don'T need that magic at all. Try using `E::value_type *` or `E::pointer`. If it has `data()` it is likely to be a container and provide public typedefs.

Comment: @Johannes thank you. actually was trying to write wrappers to work transparently with ublas and other things. Unfortunately ublas data() interface is a little bit nonstandard (array_type) so I ended up specializing it separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC's nonstandard [typeof](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) operator can do this, as can [Boost.TypeOf](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/typeof.html).

Comment: that seems to work, provided there are no overloaded functions.
Do you know how to deal with case where there is 2 functions (one has const qualifier)

Comment: You would need to typecast the function to the const or non const type before using it. You get the same problem with boost::bind.

Comment: @brad thank you. Dont I need to know return type before type cast?
can you give an example?

Comment: The problem is described with boost::bind here and how to handle it.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/bind/bind.html#err_overloade

Answer (score 3):

If you're using VS2010 or GCC 4.3 at least you can use C++0x new keyword [`decltype`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype) .